# How do I enable the text editer in my WordPress theme?

Tags: customization, custom-field, uploads, text

My text editor seems to be broken. I can reproduce this issue on cPanel. I clean-installed everything 2-3x and this issue still persists. I wasn't able to reproduce it on Managed WordPress. I am using the latest version of WordPress and OnePress (theme).

Steps
1. Install and activate OnePress demo theme in WordPress
2. Go to Dashboard
3. Click Appearance in the left-hand menu
4. Click Customize
5. Click Section: About
6. Click Section Settings
7. Attempt to edit text in Section Description

Result: Unable to add text in all "Section Description" fields for all sections' See [result screenshot](https://s28.postimg.org/mj8fdabzh/result.jpg)

Expected Result: Text editor is disabled; see [expected_results screenshot](https://s23.postimg.org/4gtlal15n/expected_result.jpg)

Comment: I tested the issue against OnePress v.1.2.7 to 1.2.9 and the the text editor is only disabled in Section: Features - Section Content - Description (textbox)

Comment: 1.2.4 is broken against the latest version of WordPress. All other versions have a bug as described in my previous post. I believe in version 1.2.5 I was unable to change font-awesome icons in Section: Features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Steps
1. Go to WordPress dashboard
2. Click on username at the top bar
3. Click "Edit My Profile"
4. Uncheck "Disable the visual editor when writing"
5. Scroll to the bottom and click "Update Profile"